# Relativistic aerobraking

Tags: jupiter, aerobraking

If I have a spacecraft flying at 90 percent the speed of light and it slams into Jupiter's upper atmosphere, by how much would it slow down?

It's for a story idea.

Thanks.

Comment: Before it evaporates, or after?

Comment: Here's an XKCD with some relevance https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/ . Basically, your spacecraft would vaporize, and probably blast the planet apart.

Comment: @GdB no way would it damage the planet. I did some calculations of kinetic energy for a relativistic spaceship and it's nowhere near the kinetic energy of a large asteroid. For example a 1000t ship@90%c has a kE of 1.17x10^24J : this is roughly equal to a rocky asteroid with a radius of 65km hitting at 20000m/s: now that is one big-ass asteroid and could probably wipe out life on Earth but the planet itself would shrug it off. Jupiter would have been smacked regularly by asteroids/comets with that kind of energy. The ship would need to be A LOT bigger, or a LOT faster to threaten a plant.

Comment: I think it will be easier to get the spacecraft moving with such speed than to protect it from evaporating at the collision with atmosphere's particle. By the time we will have this technology, we will have the deceleration free hard landing too.

Comment: Are you looking for a serious answer? Does the ship wish to slow down and remain intact, or to simply self-destruct? Can it navigate? Is the plan to graze a low density part of the upper atmosphere, or to plunge head-long into the planet as a direct hit? Is it a big ship, or a nano-ship (e.g. Breakthrough Starshot sized) with molecular beings? There is some real physics to be considered in some of these cases. Please make edits directly to the question, don't reply in comments. Thanks!